# MySQL-Query: Limit to all rows with value X of first row

Tags: mysql

My table is in this way:

- ID / VALUE1 / VALUE 2
- 1 / 99 / test
- 2 / 99 / test
- 3 / 99 / test
- 4 / 99 / test
- 5 / 98 / test
- 6 / 98 / test

I just want in this case just all values WHERE VALUE 1 = 99. But this value can change trough the time. So it can be also this case:

- 1 / 100 / test
- 2 / 99 / test
- 3 / 99 / test
- 4 / 99 / test
- 5 / 98 / test
- 6 / 98 / test

Here I want just to query all values Where VALUE1 = 100

Could you help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "this value can change trough the time" but if it's _I'd like to use the query for different values_, use a variable in your query. The implementation will depend on your language.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous!

Comment: Perhaps you need to use a subquery: Select * From table Where Value1 = (Select Value1 from table where ID = 1);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out all the rows of data with value1=99 do:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE value1=99;
```

If you would want to include the rows where value1=100 too then do:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE value1=99 OR value1=100;
```

See [mysqltutorial.org](http://mysqltutorial.org) for more helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is hard to understand I'm not sure this is the answer

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT value1 FROM Table where id=1) t2 ON t2.Value1=t1.Value1
```